# Trying to group a range of values on X-Axis in R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, visualization

Below is a part of the dataset i'm using to visualise.

```
**Merchandise   Stores  Year    Total Sales**
White goods Shop01  2015    45,547,000
White goods Shop02  2015    28,775,000
White goods Shop03  2015    17,029,000
White goods Shop04  2015    28,827,000
White goods Shop05  2015    38,929,000
White goods Shop06  2015    10,740,000
White goods Shop07  2015    15,008,000
White goods Shop08  2015    10,013,000
White goods Shop09  2015    14,556,000
White goods Shop10  2015    10,669,000
Groceries   Shop01  2015    14,334,000
Groceries   Shop02  2015    6,521,000
Groceries   Shop03  2015    30,025,000
Groceries   Shop04  2015    5,899,000
Groceries   Shop05  2015    5,333,919
Groceries   Shop06  2015    1,915,000
Groceries   Shop07  2015    8,312,000
Groceries   Shop08  2015    4,053,000
Groceries   Shop09  2015    3,506,000
Groceries   Shop10  2015    3,492,000
```

I'm trying to group the **Total.Sales** into a range of values so that it's not too big for the plot. The code I tried is:

```
p <- ggplot(dat, aes(x=Year, y=Total.Sales, fill=Stores)) + geom_area() + scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(0, 100000, 1000000, 5000000, 10000000, 150000000))
```

This gives me an error saying **"Discrete value supplied to continuous scale"**
Don't know what I'm missing here as I'm new to R. Kindly Help.

**UPDATE**
Output after Roland's suggestion:
[My Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGbcB.png)

**Desired output:**
[Expected visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqALo.png)

**dput(dat):**

```
structure(list(Merchandise = structure(c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Clothes", "Groceries", "Home goods", 
"White goods"), class = "factor"), Stores = structure(c(1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 10L), .Label = c("Shop01", "Shop02", "Shop03", "Shop04", 
"Shop05", "Shop06", "Shop07", "Shop08", "Shop09", "Shop10"), class = "factor"), 
    Year = c(2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
    2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
    2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
    2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
    2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 
    2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 
    2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 
    2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 
    2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 
    2014L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 
    2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 
    2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 
    2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 
    2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 
    2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 
    2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 
    2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 
    2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 
    2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 
    2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 
    2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 
    2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 
    2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L), Total.Sales = c(45547000, 28775000, 
    17029000, 28827000, 38929000, 10740000, 15008000, 10013000, 
    14556000, 10669000, 14334000, 6521000, 30025000, 5899000, 
    5333919, 1915000, 8312000, 4053000, 3506000, 3492000, 11601000, 
    7730000, 7519000, 14426000, 7046000, 1875000, 7902000, 6775000, 
    6063000, 15843000, 19047000, 8250000, 21218000, 7161000, 
    6812000, 1728000, 9807000, 5543000, 5012000, 4790000, 71817000, 
    43940000, 35523000, 56430000, 70254000, 19149000, 28253000, 
    133249000, 27730000, 25198000, 15233000, 10179000, 24703000, 
    9482000, 8850000, 2800000, 11749000, 8734000, 7753000, 7698000, 
    10135000, 9094000, 8669000, 11978000, 8438000, 2391000, 9526000, 
    7978000, 8791000, 13948000, 18087000, 8626000, 21835000, 
    6935000, 6134000, 2380000, 9306000, 5787000, 4388000, 4755000, 
    80738000, 43987000, 51321000, 54873000, 73234000, 18765000, 
    38748000, 103439000, 36943000, 27176000, 12348000, 95600000, 
    18047000, 9104000, 8190000, 2096000, 9719000, 7557000, 7503000, 
    6918000, 7530000, 5456000, 5452000, 7459000, 5218000, 1615000, 
    5613000, 4532000, 4147000, 6534000, 18168000, 7462000, 19321000, 
    5819000, 5733269, 1994284, 8622000, 5745984, 4532426, 4395000, 
    71823000, 38904000, 35842000, 57027000, 52850000, 19012000, 
    28645000, 0, 0, 0, 10408000, 7429000, 10915000, 6997000, 
    5571000, 1559000, 8543000, 0, 0, 0, 7314000, 5396000, 5041000, 
    9620000, 4468000, 1304000, 5426000, 0, 0, 0, 13694000, 7615000, 
    20337000, 7569000, 6201000, 135200, 8673000, 0, 0, 0, 65325000, 
    47179000, 29659000, 37861000, 58183000, 16129000, 23828000, 
    0, 0, 0, 13237000, 8825000, 13981000, 7841000, 4597000, 1155589, 
    13109000, 0, 0, 0, 6412000, 4998000, 4776000, 8306000, 5749000, 
    1539000, 6013000, 0, 0, 0, 16683000, 6223000, 17941000, 5740000, 
    4019000, 1453000, 7130000, 0, 0, 0), Latitude = c(-37.8594, 
    -37.8532, -38.3697, -34.3698, -33.4187, -31.0025, -28.8214, 
    -42.8826, -27.405, -28.0632, -37.8594, -37.8532, -38.3697, 
    -34.3698, -33.4187, -31.0025, -28.8214, -42.8826, -27.405, 
    -28.0632, -37.8594, -37.8532, -38.3697, -34.3698, -33.4187, 
    -31.0025, -28.8214, -42.8826, -27.405, -28.0632, -37.8594, 
    -37.8532, -38.3697, -34.3698, -33.4187, -31.0025, -28.8214, 
    -42.8826, -27.405, -28.0632, -37.8594, -37.8532, -38.3697, 
    -34.3698, -33.4187, -31.0025, -28.8214, -42.8826, -27.405, 
    -28.0632, -37.8594, -37.8532, -38.3697, -34.3698, -33.4187, 
    -31.0025, -28.8214, -42.8826, -27.405, -28.0632, -37.8594, 
    -37.8532, -38.3697, -34.3698, -33.4187, -31.0025, -28.8214, 
    -42.8826, -27.405, -28.0632, -37.8594, -37.8532, -38.3697, 
    -34.3698, -33.4187, -31.0025, -28.8214, -42.8826, -27.405, 
    -28.0632, -37.8594, -37.8532, -38.3697, -34.3698, -33.4187, 
    -31.0025, -28.8214, -42.8826, -27.405, -28.0632, -37.8594, 
    -37.8532, -38.3697, -34.3698, -33.4187, -31.0025, -28.8214, 
    -42.8826, -27.405, -28.0632, -37.8594, -37.8532, -38.3697, 
    -34.3698, -33.4187, -31.0025, -28.8214, -42.8826, -27.405, 
    -28.0632, -37.8594, -37.8532, -38.3697, -34.3698, -33.4187, 
    -31.0025, -28.8214, -42.8826, -27.405, -28.0632, -37.8594, 
    -37.8532, -38.3697, -34.3698, -33.4187, -31.0025, -28.8214, 
    -42.8826, -27.405, -28.0632, -37.8594, -37.8532, -38.3697, 
    -34.3698, -33.4187, -31.0025, -28.8214, -42.8826, -27.405, 
    -28.0632, -37.8594, -37.8532, -38.3697, -34.3698, -33.4187, 
    -31.0025, -28.8214, -42.8826, -27.405, -28.0632, -37.8594, 
    -37.8532, -38.3697, -34.3698, -33.4187, -31.0025, -28.8214, 
    -42.8826, -27.405, -28.0632, -37.8594, -37.8532, -38.3697, 
    -34.3698, -33.4187, -31.0025, -28.8214, -42.8826, -27.405, 
    -28.0632, -37.8594, -37.8532, -38.3697, -34.3698, -33.4187, 
    -31.0025, -28.8214, -42.8826, -27.405, -28.0632, -37.8594, 
    -37.8532, -38.3697, -34.3698, -33.4187, -31.0025, -28.8214, 
    -42.8826, -27.405, -28.0632, -37.8594, -37.8532, -38.3697, 
    -34.3698, -33.4187, -31.0025, -28.8214, -42.8826, -27.405, 
    -28.0632), Longitude = c(144.7994, 147.5463, 142.4617, 150.6471, 
    149.5702, 150.1511, 153.26, 147.3216, 152.4424, 148.2859, 
    144.7994, 147.5463, 142.4617, 150.6471, 149.5702, 150.1511, 
    153.26, 147.3216, 152.4424, 148.2859, 144.7994, 147.5463, 
    142.4617, 150.6471, 149.5702, 150.1511, 153.26, 147.3216, 
    152.4424, 148.2859, 144.7994, 147.5463, 142.4617, 150.6471, 
    149.5702, 150.1511, 153.26, 147.3216, 152.4424, 148.2859, 
    144.7994, 147.5463, 142.4617, 150.6471, 149.5702, 150.1511, 
    153.26, 147.3216, 152.4424, 148.2859, 144.7994, 147.5463, 
    142.4617, 150.6471, 149.5702, 150.1511, 153.26, 147.3216, 
    152.4424, 148.2859, 144.7994, 147.5463, 142.4617, 150.6471, 
    149.5702, 150.1511, 153.26, 147.3216, 152.4424, 148.2859, 
    144.7994, 147.5463, 142.4617, 150.6471, 149.5702, 150.1511, 
    153.26, 147.3216, 152.4424, 148.2859, 144.7994, 147.5463, 
    142.4617, 150.6471, 149.5702, 150.1511, 153.26, 147.3216, 
    152.4424, 148.2859, 144.7994, 147.5463, 142.4617, 150.6471, 
    149.5702, 150.1511, 153.26, 147.3216, 152.4424, 148.2859, 
    144.7994, 147.5463, 142.4617, 150.6471, 149.5702, 150.1511, 
    153.26, 147.3216, 152.4424, 148.2859, 144.7994, 147.5463, 
    142.4617, 150.6471, 149.5702, 150.1511, 153.26, 147.3216, 
    152.4424, 148.2859, 144.7994, 147.5463, 142.4617, 150.6471, 
    149.5702, 150.1511, 153.26, 147.3216, 152.4424, 148.2859, 
    144.7994, 147.5463, 142.4617, 150.6471, 149.5702, 150.1511, 
    153.26, 147.3216, 152.4424, 148.2859, 144.7994, 147.5463, 
    142.4617, 150.6471, 149.5702, 150.1511, 153.26, 147.3216, 
    152.4424, 148.2859, 144.7994, 147.5463, 142.4617, 150.6471, 
    149.5702, 150.1511, 153.26, 147.3216, 152.4424, 148.2859, 
    144.7994, 147.5463, 142.4617, 150.6471, 149.5702, 150.1511, 
    153.26, 147.3216, 152.4424, 148.2859, 144.7994, 147.5463, 
    142.4617, 150.6471, 149.5702, 150.1511, 153.26, 147.3216, 
    152.4424, 148.2859, 144.7994, 147.5463, 142.4617, 150.6471, 
    149.5702, 150.1511, 153.26, 147.3216, 152.4424, 148.2859, 
    144.7994, 147.5463, 142.4617, 150.6471, 149.5702, 150.1511, 
    153.26, 147.3216, 152.4424, 148.2859)), .Names = c("Merchandise", 
"Stores", "Year", "Total.Sales", "Latitude", "Longitude"), row.names = c(NA, 
-200L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Your sales are not numbers. Try your code after running `dat$Total.Sales <- as.numeric(gsub(",", "", dat$Total.Sales, fixed = TRUE))`.

Comment: Hi, I tried running this and then running my code. It worked but the output doesn't seem to have come out well. I have posted the image in the main question. Any feedback on it is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please add the output of `dput(dat)` to your question. It's also unclear what you expect as output.

Comment: Sorry about that. I've edited my post again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried using ggplot2 to create your desired plot but I failed to create the continuous plot.

The closest I got was when I used ggvis:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggvis)
ggvis(dat, x=~Year, y=~Total.Sales, fill=~Stores) %>% group_by(Stores) %>% layer_bars
```

The code above creates this:
[image]

I hope this helps

Comment: This is great. Thanks a ton! Can I facet this according to "Merchandise"?

Comment: Sure. You need to add a `filter` function, e.g.: `ggvis(dat, x=~Year, y=~Total.Sales, fill=~Stores) %>% filter(Merchandise=='Clothes') %>% group_by(Stores) %>% layer_bars`

Comment: Awesome. Worked perfectly! Thanks again for your help!